# Using new Paypal Rest API does not accept payment in GBP

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, bad-request

I get a 400: Bad Request error when trying to make payment in GBP, where as USD is working fine. I am getting this error since last few days earlier it was working fine, I think the issue has started after Paypal has made changes to its site rencently.

Also all the payment is going to a default sandbox account (it has a word facilitator appended to it, I did not create this account) I am not sure if I can change and set a sandbox account that I created as default account for receiving payment. Any idea?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the REST API's only support USD, passing a different currency can cause errors to be generated.  There are plans to eventually support additional currencies, but currently it is only set up for USD.

Comment: also please confirm is this issue for "Development" account only and will live Paypal account accept payment in GBP with the new Rest API ?

Comment: Live will only support USD at this time, until the additional support is added for other currencies.  I do not have an ETA at this time as to when this will happen.